# How do I implement 'search' in my database?

Tags: mysql, database

So I have around 6 tables with 6 columns each, like, address,name etc. I have to implement a search feature where the user enters a 'word' and I have to search my entire database(all 6 tables) to find the word, and when the word is found, that particular row should be returned from that table. Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all six tables have the same column names you can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 
    col1 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col2 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR 
    col3 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col4 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR 
    col4 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col6 LIKE '%searchValue%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE 
    col1 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col2 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR 
    col3 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col4 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR 
    col4 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col6 LIKE '%searchValue%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE3 WHERE 
    col1 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col2 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR 
    col3 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col4 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR 
    col4 LIKE '%searchValue%' OR col6 LIKE '%searchValue%'
 and so on...
```

If the six tables have different column name you can still use the `union all` but before you have to rename the column so that every select return the same column name

```
SELECT col_a as COL1, col_b as COL2, col_c AS COL3, col_d AS COL4, col_e AS COL5, col_f as COL6 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ....
UNION ALL
SELECT col_q as COL1, col_w as COL2, col_e AS COL3, col_r AS COL4, col_t AS COL5, col_y as COL6 FROM TABLE2 WHERE ....
etc..
```

If neither of the two queries above will work for your purpose you can still use the single queries, doing six different select statements.

Comment: In the case of the `union` example, I'm guessing the table (`TABLE1`, `TABLE2`, etc) that a record is found in is also important and should be included in each row, otherwise one would have no idea which table the search result is coming from.  I'd be tempted to stick to separate queries to make it more obvious (unless it's vital that the search is done in one query, in which case I'd use a stored procedure).

Comment: you can always know from which table the result in, just adding a simple static column in each select... ie `select table_1 as name ... from table1.... union all select table_2 as name from table2...` etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the LIKE clause and wildcards. (Example for php)

```
'Select * FROM Table_Nam WHERE column_Nam1 LIKE %' . $searchValue . '%'.
    'OR column_Nam2 LIKE %' . $searchValue . '%'.
    'OR column_Nam3 LIKE %' . $searchValue . '%'.
    'OR column_Nam4 LIKE %' . $searchValue . '%'.
    'OR column_Nam5 LIKE %' . $searchValue . '%'.
    'OR column_Nam6 LIKE %' . $searchValue . '%'.;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google - MySQL Fulltext Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL+Full+Text+Search)

Comment: mysql documentation is extremely intimidating

Comment: Changed link, this link shouldn't get invalid :)